# Access denied of random Global Resources in Azure application

Tags: parsing, azure, file-io, resx, access-denied

Whenever I run the web application, it is fine and the login screen shows. However, when I run the web application **in the Azure emulator things go wrong**.

It cannot execute the operation "CreateFile" on a *random* resource file, as shown below, look at the bottom two entries where the result is "ACCESS DENIED". The language of my system is Dutch (nl-NL) so that doesn't have to do with it.
[image: access denied on resource file]

I have opened the properties of these events and they are posted below:
[image: properties of first access denied]
[image: properties of second access denied]

The process w3wp.exe is run under NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and this account has full rights on the parent directory and the actual files inside the directory.

Two additional notes:

- I have fully updated Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012, Azure SDK October 2012 etc.
- A colleague of mine has got it all up and running with no seemingly changes on his end.

Do you guys have any idea why this happens? *Again, it only happens when run in Azure.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the following didn't hold when I double-checked it:

> The process w3wp.exe is run under NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and this account has full rights on the parent directory and the actual files inside the directory.

Only the parent directories had the combination of NETWORK SERVICE and the rights imposed, the individual files didn't. After explicitly setting the rights on the files, the problem was solved.